# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to override the below `<object>` width and height value that are created by an iframe - below is the JS snippet I tried to overwrite it, but in the console it returns with the error of ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of null***

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="videoPlayerSWF" data="http://videoplayer.vevo.com/embed/embedded" width="1794" height="1082"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"></object>   

 document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").height='100%';
 document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").width='100%';
```

Comment: Are you using onload to make sure the page is loaded before attempting to access its content?

Comment: Have you tried waiting to load the window? window.onload = function() { ... } ?

Comment: If the code is outside the iFrame, you are subject to XSS rules. You would also need to get the iFrames' handle to use `getElementById` on.

Comment: I am waiting for the DOM to load using $(window).bind("load", function() {};

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").height='100%';
   document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").width='100%';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/YLJa7/2/

- set it on ready
- make sure you parent have height as well, otherwise it won't be 100%

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").style.width = "100%";
```

Comment: The error indicates the getElementById is returning null, meaning the element with the given id could not be bound; as it does exist in the markup the js call must precede its insertion into the DOM.